# Writing Astropy Units for Matlab / What is the software architecture?

Tags: matlab, numpy, astropy

Matlab has no feature like [Astropy Units](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/).  This feature allows units to be attached to numerical data in Python.  The units can be factored, multiplied, divided, simplified.  It provides errors when numerical data with units is added to numerical data with either the wrong units or no units at all.

Data with units can be manipulated in linear algebra, FFT, ... with NumPy.  The units are also displayed in LaTex and on figure axes.

Though I understand OOP concepts, I don't understand how Astropy was written without a massive re-write of NumPy (et al.).

How is it that NumPy can accept Astopy unit labeled objects without re-writing every method in NumPy?

Comment: No clue what "the feature" is, you are missing in MATLAB. It can't be an astronomy toolbox in general, such a thing is available in MATLAB.

Comment: Sorry about the oversight.  I meant Astropy Units specifically.  Is this acceptable now?

Comment: Much better now, already voted to reopen. Still there are units in matlab: https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/units-of-measurement-tutorial.html

Comment: Candidly, I'm interested in the software architecture as much as the feature.

Comment: When you say that you can compute the FFT of an Astropy `Quantity` object using `numpy.fft`, does it actually give you a `Quantity` object back with the right quantities? Or does it return a plain old NumPy array? I would presume the latter. If so, then these objects likely implement the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html). Objects that implement the buffer protocol can be used as input to any NumPy function, to NumPy they look like an array. But to allow the FFT to return a `Quantity` object with the right units, you'd need to write a new `fft` function.

Comment: Generally speaking numpy functions called with a `Quantity` will return a `Quantity` with the correct units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astropy `Quantity` is a subclass of the numpy `ndarray` class. It provides the `__array_function__` method (https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html) which allows overriding the behavior of numpy function.

If you are interested in the software architecture you should go ahead and look at the source code:

https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/units/quantity.py

Comment: I was gonna say, re "I don't understand how Astropy was written without a massive re-write of NumPy"--it sort of did.  Not a complete rewrite of course, but things like `__array_function__` and `__array_ufunc__` didn't exist yet when we first started trying to do this, and while it worked to an extent even in the first draft, this made it much, *much* better.